# Showing that $x^{2m+2}-x^{2m}-x^2+1\geq 0$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I am trying to show that the polynomial

$$x^{2m+2}-x^{2m}-x^2+1$$

is always greater than or equal to $0$.

Is there a trick to this? I don't think calculus will work.

Comment: what is $m$ ? any conditions on it?

Comment: Note that your polynomial factors as $ \ (x^2 \ - \ 1 ) \ \cdot \ ( x^{2m} \ - \ 1 ) \ $ .  As "differences of even powers", both factors have well-understood factors in turn.

Answer (score 2):

$x^{2m+2}-x^{2m}-x^2+1=x^{2m}(x^2-1)-(x^2-1)=(x^2-1)(x^{2m}-1)$. If $|x|<1$ then both terms are negative, hence the product is positive. And if $|x|>1$ then both terms are positive. Finally, the expression is zero if $x=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$x^{2m+2}-x^{2m}-x^2+1=x^{2m}(x^2-1)-(x^2-1)$$

Finish the factorization, and show that if one factor is negative, so is the other.